# Unable to find a type from WSDL

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl

I am trying to consume the following web service in order to get a list of online quiz results. Unfortunately help from the provider is not forthcoming. Their other web services work fine for us; its just this one we're struggling with.

https://opendoor.lg.lumesse.com/webservices/services/LearningStatusRecords?wsdl

The manual specifies the following:

> “LearningStatusRecords” service includes two methods:
>
> 1. FetchLearningStatusRecords
> 2. AcknowledgeLearningStatusRecords The main functionality is handled by ‘FetchLearningStatusRecords’ method.
>
> Response return:
>
> 1. up to 1000 records with user information, activity information, results and relevant dates,
> 2. flag if there are more records to retrieve,
> 3. unique token for retrieved records (no token if none records retrieved)

If I follow the WSDL file correctly, there should be an object I can instantiate called `LearningStatusRecords`, but IntelliSense doesn't show this:

[image]

I can instantiate `FetchLearningStatusRecordsRequest`, and get access to the properties the manual describes, but then can't find any way to associate that request with a response.

The more I read about WSDL files the more confusing this is getting.  I also see entries in web.config saying there are some issues, but aren't sure whether those are causing this problem or not.

Comment: @halfer - thanks for tidying up my panic-riddled mess :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I see:

Try this is tested and is passed:

```
using ServiceReference1;

public class ServiceTestClass
{
    public ServiceTestClass()
    {
        using (var client = new LearningStatusRecordsPortTypeClient())
        {
             LearningStatusRecordsFetchResponse result1 = client.FetchLearningStatusRecords(
           new LearningStatusRecordsFetchRequest());

               foreach (LearningStatusRecord lsr in result1.LearningStatusRecordsList)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(lsr.RecordStatus);
                }

           LearningStatusRecordsAcknowledgeResponse result2 =  client.AcknowledgeLearningStatusRecords(
                new LearningStatusRecordsAcknowledgeRequest());
        }
    }
}
```

When You add wsdl to ServiceReference You can see what type is for cilent class in this example is `LearningStatusRecordsPortTypeClient`

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  You've made more progress in ten minutes than me all day so far...  Please tell me, how do I get access to the collection that is returned in the response?  Do I need to create a variable that references client.FetchLearningStatusRecords then iterate the collection inside it?

Comment: No, all types are generated automaticly. You must only know right date to class `LearningStatusRecordsFetchReques`t and `LearningStatusRecordsAcknowledgeRequest`. Class for response have Response in name.  I update my ansswer to show witch class is for witch method  @EvilDr Remeber is answer is corect mark You accept answer

Comment: I'm going to add a bounty as thank you today.  Could I just check, within `result2` there is a property called `acknowledgeSuccessful` that i can set to `true`.  Do I need to then send that value back to the service to finish the acknowledgement?  Is there a method to *save* the `true` value to the service?

Comment: There is not method Save or Update. Service is like ping-pong. You send request and You get response. I You want to change something You must  create request and get the response.

Comment: The manual says that the service returns 1000 rows of data maximum.  When the acknowledge token is sent, you can get the next 1000 rows.  If no token is sent, you always get the same 1000 rows.  Therefore I just need to know how to send that token back please.

Comment: OK, I think You can get token and pass to next request to `FetchLearningStatusRecords` method. You must create next request with token

Comment: Got it!  Youre code can be changed to `LearningStatusRecordsAcknowledgeResponse result2 = client.AcknowledgeLearningStatusRecords(new LearningStatusRecordsAcknowledgeRequest() { acknowledgeToken = result1.acknowledgeToken } );` which passes the token back to the server.